# gridded data bilinear interpolation MATLAB

Tags: matlab, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I have a tabulated data[image]

which I like to use bi-linear interpolation between data (orange highlight in image) in MATLAB.
I don't know how to use interp1 or interp2.

if i assume that the blue row is x, and the blue column is y and the data between is k(x,y). so I have three vector and I am going to expand vector x and later vector y as well, to interpolate data.

would you please help me?

I'd appreciate any help and comment.

Comment: no, and Actually I don't know how! could you please give me a simple example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [griddata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) or Delaulay triangulization methods, such as [TriScatteredInterp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triscatteredinterpclass.html)

Comment: could you give me a simple example to try griddata?

Comment: There are examples in the link I gave. Also a simple google search will give you much more, like [this one](http://damp.coas.oregonstate.edu/matlab_gridding/)

Comment: about `griddata`, we know that the format of command is `vq`=`griddata`(x,y,v, xq,yq), I don't know how to define `xq`, `yq` ! I saw that we should use [xq,yq]=`meshgrid`(???), but how we will define inside! I'd appreciate your help